# Return value of two functions are equal in Prolog

Tags: prolog, comparison

I have a movie database with terms like

```
movie(blood_simple, 1984).
movie(the_cotton_club, 1984).
movie(american_beauty, 1999).
...
```

I'd like to write a function which returns true if the two given movies were released in the same year and false if they were not.

I have problem with comparing two values, my function always returns false.

Here is my code:

```
sameyear(Movie1,Movie2):-
    movie(Movie1,Year1),
    movie(Movie2,Year2).
    % here I tried comparing Year1 with Year2 like: Year1 == Year2, Year1 =:= Year2, nothing worked.
```

Another code:

```
sameyear(Movie1,Movie2):-
    movie(Movie1,Year1),
    movie(Movie2,Year1).    % here I expected that it would return true if the movies were released at the
 same year, because Year1 has already got a value at *movie(Movie1,Year1)*, but that didn't happen
```

Can you help me?

Comment: The second code fragment is correct. What is not working with that?

Comment: It is, I was wrong. But can I refer to the output of a function? For example in  movie(Movie1,Year1), Year1 gets a value, but I cannot refer to it, as in the first code segment.

Comment: I don't really get why you can not refer to it? It is unified with `Year1`, so if you want to constrain it further (i.e. `Year1 > 1990` for example), that is perfectly possible.

Comment: The thing that doesn't work for me is to compare Year1 with Year two. Why is *Year1 == Year2, Year1 =:= Year2* incorrect?

Comment: you wrote a dot at the end of `movie(movie2, Year2)`, so that means the predicate is "finished".

Comment: I didn't notice that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote a dot (`.`) at the end of the `movie(Movie2, Year2)` clause. THis thus means that you end the predicate. If you then write `Year1 == Year2.`, then this is another rule.

You thus should use a comma, which is semantically close to the *logical and*:

```
sameyear(Movie1,Movie2):-
    movie(Movie1,Year1),
    movie(Movie2,Year2),  % ← added a comma
    Year1 == Year2.
```

This then produces:

```
?- sameyear(M1, M2).
M1 = M2, M2 = blood_simple ;
M1 = blood_simple,
M2 = the_cotton_club ;
M1 = the_cotton_club,
M2 = blood_simple ;
M1 = M2, M2 = the_cotton_club ;
M1 = M2, M2 = american_beauty.
```